# static method in c# returns only one boolean?

Tags: c#

I have this noob question. 
I want to ask why my static method only returns one boolean instead of two(if the condition is true). I thought that if my loop returns true, the program will also return false because it is outside of the loop and there is no condition, so it will be always satisfied and will return the false boolean.

```java
static void Main(string[] args) {
    Console.WriteLine(trippleCheck(new [] { 2, 2, 1, 2, 3 }));
}
static bool trippleCheck(int[] myArray) {
    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length - 1; i++) {
        if (myArray[i] == myArray[i + 1] && myArray[i] == myArray[i + 2]) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. `return` means the method returns, it "stops executing" if you want to think about it that way. So if the `if`-statement hits the condition and `return true;` is executed, it means the method returns, no more code in that method gets to execute.

Comment: And none of what I said above has anything to do with it being a static method. All methods only return once. (if we leave iterator methods out of it, which are special)

Comment: You're asking why the code does _what you would want_ in this situation (`return`ing `true` if three consecutive, identical elements are found) instead of something completely different?  If you thought the `return false` would always take effect then why would you code it this way instead of `bool found = false; for ( ... ) { if (myArray[i] == myArray[i + 1] && myArray[i] == myArray[i + 2]) { found = true;  break; } } return found;`?

Comment: The best way to understand what your code is doing is to [run it in a debugger](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/).

Comment: Are you coming from a language like VB([.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/how-to-return-a-value-from-a-procedure#to-return-a-value-using-exit-function-or-end-function)) where returning a value from a function is/can be done by assigning to a variable with the same name as the function?  That is, did you think that in C# `return` is assigning that value to a hidden variable to be returned to the caller when the function completes but without the `return` otherwise impacting flow within the function?

Answer (score 1):

return statements end the function immediately and **return** execution to the caller.

Comment: I think you're first paragraph answers the question for the OP. The second paragraph isn't what the OP is asking about and just adds noise and confusion.